# Reading values from a file and outputting each number, largest/smallest numbers, sum, and average of numbers from the file

Tags: python-3.x

The issue that I am having is that I am able to read the information from the files, but when I try to convert them from a string to an integer, I get an error. I also have issues where the min/max prints as the entire file's contents.

I have tried using if/then statements as well as using different variables for each line in the file.

```
file=input("Which file do you want to get the data from?")
f=open('data3.txt','r')
sent='-999'
line=f.readline().rstrip('\n')
while len(line)>0:
    lines=f.read().strip('\n')
    value=int(lines)
    if value>value:
        max=value
        print(max)
    else:
        min=value
        print(min)
    total=sum(lines)
    print(total)
```

I expect the code to find the min/max of the numbers in the file as well as the sum and average of the numbers in the file. The results from the file being processed in the code, then have to be written to a different file. My results have consisted in various errors reading that Python is unable to convert from a str to an int as well as printing the entire file's contents instead of the expected results.

Comment: Please include some sample data as well as the full error message (traceback).

Comment: `print(repr(value))` before you convert it to see if it looks like an integer, or use a source debugger and step through your code.

Answer (score 0):

does the following work?

```
lines = list(open('fileToRead.txt'))
intLines = [int(i) for i in lines]
maxValue = max(intLines)
minvalue = min(intLines)
sumValue = sum(intLines)
print("MaxValue : {0}".format( maxValue))
print("MinValue : {0}".format(minvalue))
print("Sum : {0}".format(sumValue))
print("Avergae : {0}".format(sumValue/len(intLines)))
```

and this is how my `filesToRead.txt` is formulated (just a simple one, in fact)

```
10
20
30
40
5
1
```

I am reading file contents into a list. Then I create a new list (it can be joined with the previous step as part of some code refactoring) which has all the list of ints.Once when I have the list of ints, its easier to calculate `max` and `min` on it.

Note that *some of the variables are not named properly*. Also reading the whole file in one go (like what I have done here) *might be a bad idea if the file is too large*. In that case, you should never ever read the whole file in one go. In this case , you need to read it line by line, parse the ints and add them to a list of ints. Once when you are done reading the file, close the file. You can then start your calculations based on the list of ints that you have now obtained.

Please let me know if this resolves your query.

Thanks